# ReferenceField causes AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__of__' in a custom content type

Tags: plone

I have created a custom content type that has a ReferenceField.  When I set allowed_types to a default content type, such as Document or Folder, I do not get any problems upon saving or reindexing.  However, when I set allowed_types to another custom content type, I get a very strange error.  It appears I can set the UID in the ReferenceField fine and base_view does not break, but I cannot save or reindex the object.

Using:
Plone 4.0.1
Zope 2.12.11
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Nov 21 2010, 11:58:21) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)]

Any ideas?

```
atapi.ReferenceField(
    'issue_source',
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    widget=atapi.ReferenceWidget(
        label=_(u"Issue Source"),
        description=_(u"Please select the source document to which this issue corresponds."),
    ),
    required=True,
    relationship='issue_issue_source',
    allowed_types=('Source Document'), # specify portal type names here ('Example Type',)
    multiValued=False,            #One to One relationship
),
```

In ipzope:

```
>>> issue
<Issue at /Plone/Members/test_user2/test-issue>
>>> issue.isReferenceable
1
>>> source_document
<SourceDocument at /Plone/test-folder/test-doc>
>>> issue.setIssue_source(source_document.UID())
>>> issue.getIssue_source()
<SourceDocument at /Plone/test-folder/test-doc>
>>> source_document
<SourceDocument at /Plone/test-folder/test-doc>
>>> issue.reindexObject()
> /Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI-4.0-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py(77)__call__()
     76         context = aq_inner(self)
---> 77         template = template.__of__(context)
     78         return template(context, context.REQUEST)
ipdb> quit
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/Products/Archetypes/CatalogMultiplex.py", line 123, in reindexObject
    c.catalog_object(self, url, idxs=lst)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Plone-4.0.1-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/CatalogTool.py", line 287, in catalog_object
    update_metadata, pghandler=pghandler)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Products.PDBDebugMode-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/Products/PDBDebugMode/zcatalog.py", line 20, in catalog_object
    update_metadata=update_metadata, pghandler=pghandler)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/Products/ZCatalog/ZCatalog.py", line 529, in catalog_object
    update_metadata=update_metadata)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py", line 348, in catalogObject
    self.updateMetadata(object, uid)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py", line 278, in updateMetadata
    newDataRecord = self.recordify(object)
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py", line 417, in recordify
    if(attr is not MV and safe_callable(attr)): attr=attr()
  File "/Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI-4.0-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py", line 77, in __call__
    template = template.__of__(context)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__of__'
```

When I click save through the web I get a slightly different error message:

```
2011-08-09 15:19:16 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1312895956.510.252592718824 http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/Members/test_user2/test-doc/atct_edit
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module Products.PDBDebugMode.runcall, line 70, in pdb_runcall
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in _call
  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 38, in __call__
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 107, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 38, in __call__
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 1, in content_edit
   - <FSControllerPythonScript at /Plone/content_edit used for /Plone/Members/test_user2/test-doc>
   - Line 1
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 324, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 361, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 13, in content_edit_impl
   - <FSPythonScript at /Plone/content_edit_impl used for /Plone/Members/test_user2/test-doc>
   - Line 13
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 658, in processForm
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 650, in _processForm
   - __traceback_info__: (<Issue at /Plone/Members/test_user2/test-doc>, <Field nextPreviousEnabled(boolean:rw)>, <bound method Issue.setNextPreviousEnabled of <Issue at /Plone/Members/test_user2/test-doc>>)
  Module Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex, line 123, in reindexObject
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 287, in catalog_object
  Module Products.PDBDebugMode.zcatalog, line 20, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 529, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 348, in catalogObject
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 278, in updateMetadata
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 417, in recordify
  Module Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI.browserdefault, line 77, in __call__
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__of__'
> /Applications/Plone/plone-site/eggs/Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI-4.0-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py(77)__call__()
     76         context = aq_inner(self)
---> 77         template = template.__of__(context)
     78         return template(context, context.REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks strange indeed, some tips:

Pass a tuple into allowed_types instead of string:

```
allowed_types=('Source Document', ),
```

Make sure you don't have a content item with an id that matches a catalog index id. Also make sure you don't index `getIssue_source` but if you need to, use `getRawIssue_source`. Reference fields return real content objects, so using the normal accessor would store the real content objects in the catalog. That will lead to a lot of surprises and problems later on. The raw accessor returns a uuid or a list of uuids, which you can use in a catalog query like:

```
query = {'UID': uids}
brains = catalog(query)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!  Thank you so much, this is it!  I ultimately decided to set multiValued=True, as I was thinking I might have the case where 1 issue might refer to many potential source documents.